# How to create an element in javascript and pass parameters to it?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

In the new v1 web components spec, you can create a new element by saying like

```
class gg extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(a) {
        super();
    }
}

customElements.define('gg-gg', gg);
```

and then you can create a new instance of it, by doing like

```
<gg-gg></gg-gg>
```

or

```
new gg(1);
```

or even

```
document.createElement("gg-gg");
```

But in that last way `document.createElement("gg-gg")`, how would you pass a parameter into it for the `a` in the constructor?

Comment: Why would you??

Comment: You can pass parameters to functions contained within functions by just adding another set of parentheses `myFunction(par,am)(ano,ther,param)`

Comment: what does that have to do with my question though?

Comment: @omega When is the parameter expected to be used?

Comment: it could be used for something in the custom element, but the purpose of the parameter seems irrelevant to the question. Doing `new gg(1)` actually works and is in the specs, so just wanted to know if it can be done creating the element using `.createElement`.

Comment: no it's not possible. use another method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to create a `class` expression where default parameters are used to set `constructor`

```js
const gcreate = (...props) => {
  const gg = class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(a = props) {
      console.log(a);
      a.find(prop => 
        typeof prop === "object"
        && !Array.isArray(prop))
        ["def"](789)
      super();
    }
  }
  customElements.define('gg-gg', gg);
  return document.createElement("gg-gg");
}

let g = gcreate(
        // pass parameters
        "abc"
        , 123
        , [4,5,6]
        , {def:(prop) => console.log(prop)}
        , null, void 0
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass and [`options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#Parameters) object at second parameter to `document.createElement()` where property is set to `"is"`, within `contructor` use `setTimeout()` call `.getAttribute()` on variable identifier referencing `super()` to get value of `"is"` property

```js
class gg extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(a) {
        const curr = super();
        setTimeout((el) => {
          console.log(JSON.parse(el.getAttribute("is")))
        }, 0, curr)
    } 
}

customElements.define('gg-gg', gg);

const g = document.createElement("gg-gg", {"is":JSON.stringify({"abc":123})});
```

Comment: You can avoid the timeout by using     `connectedCallback() {
   alert(this.getAttribute('is'));
    }` but this way seems too verbose and restricted to strings only. Is this really the best way for passing paramters using `createElement`?

Comment: @omega What is the definition of "best"?

Comment: Something like `document.createElement('gg-gg', {}, 1);` and then `a` would be 1 in the constructor. This seems like it could be an elegant and official way that would support any type of data parameter. But if something like that isn't there, then I guess passing parameters like that is not supported.

Comment: Not certain if the specifications https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/,  https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html provide for that functionality. One alternative would be to create a function which set the parameter for `constructor` using default parameters, call the function which creates the `class` expression can call `.createElement()`

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way you can load in arguments into your constructor. It works by loading in a temp payload.

```js
// Args
var args;

// Create Element
var createElem = function (element, arguments) {
  typeof arguments === 'undefined' ? args = {} : args = arguments;
  return document.createElement('gg-gg');
}

// Define Custom Component
customElements.define('gg-gg', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(args);
  }
});

// Arguments
createElem('gg-gg', {
  width: 500,
  height: 500,
});

// No arguments
createElem('gg-gg');
```