# Is it possible to bind properties to a document.createElement element?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I want to write a custom element like this.

```
<dom-module id="custom-element">
    <template>

        <!-- This part I want to use document.createElement -->
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[data]]">

            <div>
                <span>[[item.name]]</span>
                <span>[[item.count]]</span>
            </div>

        </template>

    </template>
</dom-module>
```

The count value may be changed by other element.

Is it possible to bind properties count to a document.createElement element?

```
class CustomElement extend Polymer.Element {

    static get is () { return "custom-element" }

    static get properties () {
        return {
            data: {
                type: Array,
                value: [{
                    "name": "item1",
                    "count": 0
                }, {
                    "name": "item2",
                    "count": 0
                }, {
                    "name": "item3",
                    "count": 0
                }],
                notify: true,
                observer: "_dataChanged"
            }
        }
    }

    _dataChanged: (data) => {
        data.map((item) => {
            let div = document.createElemnt("div")

            let itemName = document.createElement("span")
                itemName.textContent = item.name

            let itemCount = document.createElement("span")

                // I want to bind value count here
                itemCount.textContent = item.count

            div.appendChild(itemName)
            div.appendChild(itemCount)

            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(div)
        })
    }

}

window.customElements.define(CustomElement.is, CustomElement)
```

When other element change the count value, the element which create by document.createElement's count will be change.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the issue with code at Question? See [How to create an element in javascript and pass parameters to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45536364/)

Comment: Hi. Does one of the answers at linked Question provide answer to present Question?

Comment: @guest271314 Hi, I use the element like this <custom-element data="[[data]]"></custom-element>, when other element changed count value, the element's count value which create by document.createElement inside the <custom-element> should be change.

Comment: Where is the other element here? can you add some bits of it? preferably the whole bit? Also, at first glance, without going through your functionality, data binding and notify work in a two way binding and not a one way binding.. use the ``{{}}`` for starters... and let us know which element are you trying to communicate with

Comment: @Schrodinger's cat Hi, about the other element, I meat the element share the same data like <custom-element data="{{data}}"> and <other-element data="{{data}}">, when <other-element> do something change the count value in the data, the count value in <custom-element> will be change at the same time, but in <custom-element> I add element by document.createElement not use html tag like this <span>[[ data.count ]]</span>, so I want to know is it possible to do data binding in script not in template?

Comment: can you create a plunker ? That would be easier to look into

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat Hi, I create a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/ob8VvxdsyxYR9uk731U0?p=preview

Comment: Hey I created my own while waiting on ya!.. see if this is what you need http://plnkr.co/edit/xhPefh?p=preview

change the data array value in `c-el2` and check if it is reflected

Comment: @Schrodinger'scat Yes, I use $0.set("mydata.0.count", 5) in the console, the value is reflected, but the element.textContent didn't, is possible to reflect value to the element.textContent too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, data binding works, **between** two **custom elements**

Whether you use a `dom-repeat` with the bind, or bind it to an element like an input in the shadow DOM,

OR,

you use `document.createElement` to append an element to your shadowDOM, with the bound value,

does not matter

you use `{{}}` for a two way binding, and a `[[]]` for a one way binding.

So, If `other-element` changes a`data` property bound to `custom-element`, and you want `custom-element` to accommodate them, use one way

If you want the changes made by `custom-elemnt` to also change values in `other-element`, use two way.

**If** you are using the `console` to mutate data of one element, I am afraid, those mutations aren't reflected to the custom element.

If however, you are having a binding between `custom-element` and `other-element` on the property `data`, and

`other-element` mutates the property `data` as the result of an event, then, these changes are notified to all communicating elements.

**Edit**: I see that you have a subsequent query in the comments, which asks why is the [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ob8VvxdsyxYR9uk731U0?p=preview) you made not working

While you are now correctly binding the elements `two-way` via `data` ,

there is a bug in polymer, that doesn't `notify` `observers` on data mutation if data is an array.

Solution for now: Shallow clone your data using slice after you change it

like so:

```
add (e) {
    this.set(`data.${e.target.index}.count`, (this.data[e.target.index].count + 1))

    this.data = this.data.slice();
  }
```

Comment: I have a little question, is this data binding <div>[[ count ]]</div> in <template> section equal to this div.textContent = count in <script> section? If equal, when I change count value the textContent should be changed at the same time. Becuse according to the data, I want to append different type element to the shaowRoot and I'm trying not use dom-if and dom-repeat.

Comment: So, a `<div>[[item.count]]</div>` in the `dom-repeat` template is equivalent to `div.textContent = item.count` in your `observer`


BUT, IF you mutate(change) the value in the console, it will not reflect. the element `other-element`, has to explicitly change it in the flow of things

your `custom-element` looks at `other-element` and not the `console`

Comment: I try in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ob8VvxdsyxYR9uk731U0?p=preview , but when I click button in `<other-element>` to change count, `<app-shell>` count did changed, but the count in `<custom-element>` didn't changed.

Comment: The data is in `app-shell` and I bind data to `custom-element` and `other-element`, in `other-element` I use `dom-repeat` to create element and it work fine when I change data in `app-shell` or in `other-element`, in `custom-element` I use documet.createElement function to create element, so my question is how to bind data to the created element like this `<div>[[ ... ]]</div>`, Is using addEventListener or something Polymer function else?

Comment: @G.CSun, Hey there is a bug open in polymer, and till it is fixed, you should use `this.data.slice()` after you change your array. see answer edits

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. `this.data.slice()` did trigger the `observer`, but the result is not what I imagined, when data changed, `custom-element` create new element not just change old  element's `textContent`, it mean when data changed, I need to remove the old element first and appendChild again. Maybe this is the only way for now.

Comment: Hmmm. Well that would mean you might have to ask a separate question @G.CSun. :) . Do ask a spearate question, If you have any doubts w.r.t to `dom-repeat` and `dom-if`. cheers!